# can't install or update apps while in mobile data plan but working in Wifi

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-6p

I have Nexus 6p phone. After the update to Android 7 my phone cannot install or update Apps from Google Play Store but it is working fine on WiFi. After Android 7.1.1 update the phone battery is draining very fast 100% = 2.5hr & heating Problem. I removed the updates for play store, changed permission too, but still nothing worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you also disabled limits in downloader, maybe firmware is  bugged? Try to carefully reflash your device.